# Updating App From New Project

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am updating an existing app.  Because of the overhaul, I'm starting over from File|New Project.  Just to see how the update would work, I ran the old version on the emulator.  I pinned the app to start.  I copied the old GUID to the new project, and while the project name is different (added a '2' to the title), I changed the Title in the WMAppManifest to be the same as the old file (title changed in both places).  Then I run the new version in the emulator.

Keeping in mind that this is a clean project, no code has been put into it.  I have deleted all the sample data, sample model view, and emptied the pivot items so it is just "first" and "second" with nothing displayed.  When I run it, that is exactly what I get.  Perfect.  Just what I wanted.  The app replaced the old app in the application list.  Wonderful.  Only one problem.  The tile that is pinned to the start screen doesn't work.  I tap it and it flickers back to the start screen.  No indication that an app is starting (no splash screen), except that for probably less than a half a second the tiles look like they're doing the turnstyle out, then back in.

I'm missing something.  When I have updated the app in the past, the tile has worked fine.  But now that I'm updating from a new project, it's not.  Also, I'm going from 7.0 to 7.1 on the project type, and while I haven't done this before, I would not expect this behavior.

Thanks for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Startup Object` to your `App` class.

[image: location in visual studio]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I looked and it is already set.  :/  The app starts fine, just not from the remnant Start Screen Tile.